# How to change the page size of one of the pages in a existing PDF using ABCPdf

Tags: c#, abcpdf

I have an existing PDF. The page size of the entire document is A4. If I would like to modify the page size of the 2nd page to Legal then How can I achieve that using ABCPdf?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that?

```
Using yourDoc As New Doc()
  With yourDoc
        .Read (yourpath)
        .PageNumber =2
        .MediaBox.String = "Legal"
        .Save(new_path)
        .Clear()
  End With
End Using
```

Page sizes: 
http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xrect/2-properties/string.htm